# I need to click on the address "Countine" button on check out page.but unable to click on it

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests

I have tried everything and nothing seems to fix issue.unable to click address continue button on checkout page.

I have written the below code but webdriver fails to  click "continue" button Please help.

```
package automationFramework;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.testng.annotations.*;

import static org.testng.Assert.*;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class CheckoutNG {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://sng.bestpricewebsitedesign.com/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void testNewCheckout() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/index.php?route=common/home");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Login")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("input-email")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("input-email")).sendKeys("leo@abc.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("input-password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("input-password")).sendKeys("asdfgh");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.btn.btn-primary")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Store")).click();



    driver.get("http://sng.bestpricewebsitedesign.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=59");
    //driver.manage().window().maximize();
    //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(6, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h4/a[text()='Yellow Tshirt']/following::span[text()='Add to Cart'][1]")).click();`    

driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/header/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[3]/a")).click();
```

I have written the below code but webdriver fails to  click "continue" button Please help.(button-payment-address is not working).

```
driver.findElement(By.id("button-payment-address")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("button-shipping-address")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("button-shipping-method")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.name("agree")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("button-payment-method")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("button-confirm")).click();
  }

  @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
   // driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
  }

  private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
      driver.findElement(by);
      return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try {
      driver.switchTo().alert();
      return true;
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
    try {
      Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
      String alertText = alert.getText();
      if (acceptNextAlert) {
        alert.accept();
      } else {
        alert.dismiss();
      }
      return alertText;
    } finally {
      acceptNextAlert = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to show your full code, but just a sample where you think the cause of issue is located. Also provide `HTML` of target button and exception log

Comment: below lines are not working.

driver.findElement(By.id("button-payment-address")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.id("button-shipping-address")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.id("button-shipping-method")).click();

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit the question with relevant code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below way to catch the exception and print it, exception will show the reason. otherwise you want be able to know the reason. most of the time reason would be element not exist.

```
public void testNewCheckout(){

  try {

    driver.findElement(By.id("button-payment-address")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("button-shipping-address")).click();


   } catch (Exception e) {

      e.printStackTrace();           

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using xpath for the button. Replace existing **testNewCheckout()** method with following:

```
@Test
public void testNewCheckout() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/index.php?route=common/home");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Login")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("input-email")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("input-email")).sendKeys("leo@abc.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("input-password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("input-password")).sendKeys("asdfgh");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.btn.btn-primary")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Store")).click();



   driver.get("http://sng.bestpricewebsitedesign.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=59");
   //driver.manage().window().maximize();
   //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(6, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h4/a[text()='Yellow Tshirt']/following::span[text()='Add to Cart'][1]")).click();`    

   driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/header/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[3]/a")).click();

   //driver.findElement(By.id("button-payment-address")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Continue']")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.id("button-shipping-address")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.id("button-shipping-method")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.name("agree")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.id("button-payment-method")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.id("button-confirm")).click();
}
```

It worked for me.